# My app has 128MB heap but uses 1.6GB of real RAM. How can I find out where the 1.4GB go to?

Tags: java, linux, memory

On linux platform, My java app on jboss has 128MB heap but uses 1.6GB of real RAM. How can I find out where the 1.4GB go to?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM  CODE DATA TIME+  COMMAND
 1379 root      16   0  9.7g 1.6g 1980 S  0.7  1.3 36  9.7g 0:11.03 java
```

thanks,
Emre

Comment: Please provide your JVM running parameters.

Comment: -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: Finally we found it is caused by the .so file loaded by JNI, it take more DATA memories. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My first step would be to examine the process in a memory profiler, such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/features/index.jsp#live_memory). This can give quite a bit of initial insight into what's *actually* happening to your process's memory usage.

Another tool that could be useful in troubleshooting this sort of issues is [`jmap`](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/10/27/summarizing-java-heap-utilization-with-jmap/).

Comment: Probably a simple `jconsole` would be enough to figure out in this case.

Comment: from jconsole, i can see heap size is nearly to 128m, but i can not see what happened about the total 1.6G size physical memory, any tool i can use to analyze it?

Comment: @EmreHe: You could try `pmap` to see if there are any large mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd find out.  But my theory is that your application has mapped a huge file as a `MemoryMappedBuffer`.  The stats in your question say that you are using 9.7 Gigabytes of address space.

Comment: i can not find "MemoryMappedBuffer" in my java code, but it invoked native method/load libary, how could i figure it out?

Comment: @EmreHe - 1) read the first sentence of my answer.  2) Look at the source code for the native methods that are being called to figure out what it is doing.  It could be ... almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "my app has 128MB heap", are you starting JBoss with -Xmx 128M ?

Anyway heap size does not determine the amount of memory your process uses, the JVM will allocate memory for other things, including a stack for each thread.

But in your case it is probably not the explanation because 1.4GB seems enormous. Are you doing something particular in your application ?

Comment: that's what want to know about what 1.6G are for.    in this jboss application, it has use some jni invoke .so library, how could i analyze it inside?

Answer (score 0):

Emre He,
according to your settings you set only perm gen start/max size.
Try to add these parameters to your JVM: -Xms128m -Xmx128m

Comment: i think Xms/Xmx is for heap size set, but i can see currently my app is has nearly 128m heap size by jconsole or jprofiler tool.